# Wrong representation rof column name in UTF-8 encoded shape in MapInfo

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, encoding, tab

I want to open an UTF-8 encoded shapefile with MapInfo (15.02). When the pop-up asks me what encoding is used, I chose UTF-8. The data contained in the table is then perfectly shown. The special characters in the column name though is not converted well. See the screenshot:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? My workaround so far is to save the opened file again as .Tab and edit the column names then.

Comment: Shapefile only has 10 bytes to represent field names. If each codepoint uses two bytes in UTF-8, that means you only have 5 characters (and some Kanji codepoints use 3-4 bytes, which means as little as 2-3 characters in names). The names you show exceed the ability of shapefile fieldname representation.

Comment: it is not about the length. it is about the wrong represtation of the underlined characters. for exampel, the last one should be "Längengra". QGIS opens the shape and the column names are perfectly right